# ColorBox - jQuery selector for all images on CDN

Tags: jquery, colorbox, cdn

I've just set-up my site to use a CDN, which has all gone according to plan, and mostly works as intended - all with the exception of colorbox, which I'm using for images.

I've got a feeling that it is no longer working because all the images have a query string on the end of them (such as `image.png?9d7bd4`), which is breaking my jQuery selector:

```
/* colorbox - use it on all links to images */
$('a[href$=".jpg"],a[href$=".jpeg"],a[href$=".png"],a[href$=".gif"]').colorbox({
    'rel': 'images',
    'photo': true,
    'maxWidth': '90%',
    'maxHeight': '90%'
});
```

Can someone help me rewrite the jQuery code to make it work? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're using is the ends with selector. You want to change it to "contains".

```
/* colorbox - use it on all links to images */
$('a[href*=".jpg"],a[href*=".jpeg"],a[href*=".png"],a[href*=".gif"]').colorbox({
    'rel': 'images',
    'photo': true,
    'maxWidth': '90%',
    'maxHeight': '90%'
});
```

More info on attribute selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Attribute_selectors

If possible however, you could add a class to the images to make selecting them easier.

Comment: @davethegrt8 - absolutely, if CLASS is allowed, much, much better for forward maintenance.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you. I could/should just use a class selector, but I kinda wanted to go for something easier to use (i.e no need for me to manually assign a class to each image I link to).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the ends-with selector you can use [contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/):

```
/* colorbox - use it on all links to images */
$('a[href*=".jpg"],a[href*=".jpeg"],a[href*=".png"],a[href*=".gif"]').colorbox({
    'rel': 'images',
    'photo': true,
    'maxWidth': '90%',
    'maxHeight': '90%'
});
```

Comment: FYI, ~= is slightly different than *= so this might cause unexpected results.

Comment: @davethegr8 - You're right, I meant to do the asterisk selector.  I edited my post.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

or in alternative to **Contains Word** you can use **Contains** selectors

```
/* colorbox - use it on all links to images */
$('a[href*=".jpg"],a[href*=".jpeg"],a[href*=".png"],a[href*=".gif"]').colorbox({
    'rel': 'images',
    'photo': true,
    'maxWidth': '90%',
    'maxHeight': '90%'
});
```

It's working for me